Prove $p \colon \mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*} \colon z \mapsto \bar{z}^{2}$ is a covering map
I'm stuck on this problem and generally struggle to show that some maps cover maps.

Consider $p \colon \mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*} \colon z \mapsto \bar{z}^{2}$. Prove that $p$ is a covering map.

I understood a similar problem, and figured a similar argument would apply here but I'm not sure it does. If we let $z \in \mathbb{C}^{*}$, then $z = e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Under $p$ we would get $p(z) = e^{-2 i \theta}$. Now I'm unsure how to choose a neighbourhood $U$ of $z$. I think it might be some slices in $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ rather than just some slice of the unit circle. If so, I don't know how to formalize it. Any help is appreciated.

It might be easier to think in terms of polar coordinates: $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ is homeomorphic, via polar coordinates, to $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times S^1$. $p$ acts on the first component by a homeomorphism $x \mapsto x^2$, and acts on the second component via reflection across the $x$-th axis, a homeomorphism, then the two-fold covering map of $S^1$ by itself.

@DavidGao This is clear thanks! Does it suffice to say each homeomorphism is a covering map and $p$ acts as a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times S^{1}$?

It is more precise to say that $p$ acts as a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}{>0} \times S^1$, then composed with identity on $\mathbb{R}{>0}$ times a (two-fold) covering map of $S^1$. That is enough to imply $p$ is a (two-fold) covering map.

Let's ignore for the moment how to choose open neighborhood $U_z$ of some $z\in\mathbb C^*$, let's say we have something that works. We want $p^{-1}(U_z)=\bigsqcup_{d\in D_z}V_d$ for some discrete space $D_z$ such that $p|_{V_d}$ is homeomorphism onto $U_z$.
Note that $$p(z) = p(w) \iff \bar z^2 = \bar w^2 \iff z^2 = w^2 \iff z = \pm w,\tag{1}$$ which tells us that $p(V) = p(-V)$, where $-V = \{-z\mid z\in V\}$.
This suggests how our covering will work, discrete space we will use should be $\{0,1\}$. Furthermore, for any $z_0\in\mathbb C^*$ we want to solve equation $\bar w^2 = z_0$ and let $\{\pm w_0\}$ be its solutions. Now choose any opet set $V_0\ni w_0$ such that $V_0\cap(-V_0)=\emptyset$ and let $U_{z_0} = p(V_0) = p(-V_0)$.
$p|_{V_0}$ and $p|_{-V_0}$ are injective because $V_0\cap(-V_0)=\emptyset$ due to $(1)$ and are onto by definition of $U_{z_0}$. Can you see that $(1)$ also implies that $p^{-1}(U_{z_0}) = V_0\cup(-V_0)$?

Yes this is clear, thanks!

Would a similar argument apply to $\pi \colon \mathbb{C}^{} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{} \colon z \mapsto \bar{z}^{4}$?

@JLGL yes. Notice how ${1,-1}$ are 2nd roots of unity and we let them act on some open subset $V_0$ by multiplication to get ${V_0,-V_0}$. For $z\mapsto \bar z^4$ you'll want to look at 4th roots of unity ${1,i,-1,-i}$ and let them act on some $V_0$ to get ${V_0,iV_0,-V_0,-iV_0}$ and you'll want them to be pairwise disjoint. Can you visualize what is going on geometrically? Think of rotations by appropriate angle.

Yes, I think so. Though I’m not sure how we guarantee $iV_{0}$ and $-V_{0}$ are disjoint?

@JLGL, make sure that $V_0$ is fully contained in some open angle (as in, part of the plane lying between two rays) of measure $90^\circ$. Imagine the four open quadrants of the plane given by real and imaginary axes and rotate it appropriately.

Aah, thanks a lot!

I’m curious, I can see how this argument can be generalized for even $n$. Could it be generalized for all $n$, how would the roots act on $V_{0}$?

@JLGL parity of $n$ doesn't matter, take all $n$-th roots of unity ${\omega_k}$ and let $V_k = \omega_kV_0$, where we act by multiplication. Geometrically, you have rotation by $2\pi/n$. Before going to the general case, make sure that you understand the case when $n = 2$ fully. For example, you can take $V_0$ to be any open half-plane and then $p(V_0)$ will be $\mathbb C$ excluding some ray starting at the origin. In fact, for any $n$ you can take $U_z$ to be $\mathbb C$ exluding some ray starting at the origin and $p^{-1}(U_z)$ will be disjoint union of $n$ open angles of measure $2\pi/n$.
